# maven Could not transfer metadata private repo : Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized

Tags: maven

When I am execute this command to build project(Mac OS X):

```
/usr/local/Cellar/maven@3.5/3.5.4/libexec/bin/mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true -U
```

throw this error:

```
Could not transfer metadata com.sports.soa:soa-room-api:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to snapshots (http://nexus.example.com/repository/maven-snapshots/): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
```

I am already config authorize info in settings xml:

```
 <server>
      <id>nexus-releases</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin123</password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin123</password>
    </server>
```

and this is my pom.xml config:

```
 <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus-releases</id>
            <name>Nexus Releases Repository Pro</name>
            <url>http://nexus.example.com/repository/maven-releases/</url>
        </repository>

        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
            <name>Nexus Snapshots Repository Pro</name>
            <url>http://nexus.example.com/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

What should I do to solve the problem(I am already tries the encrypt password,do not works)?Thanks.By the way,I can browser the repo using my config password in browser.And my repo config is:

```
 <repositories>
          <repository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>Snapshots</name>
            <snapshots>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
              <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <url>http://nexus.example.com/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
          </repository>
          <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <name>Releases</name>
            <snapshots>
              <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <url>http://nexus.example.com/repository/maven-releases/</url>
          </repository>
        </repositories>
```

Comment: What is in your `<repositories>` configuration?

Comment: I have pasted my repo config@JF Meier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the repo id to `nexus-releases` and `nexus-snapshots` fix the problem:

```
 <repositories>
          <repository>
            <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
            <name>Snapshots</name>
            <snapshots>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
              <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <url>http://nexus.example.com/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
          </repository>
          <repository>
            <id>nexus-releases</id>
            <name>Releases</name>
            <snapshots>
              <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <url>http://nexus.example.com/repository/maven-releases/</url>
          </repository>
        </repositories>
```